# Help identifying small connector

Tags: connector

I'm working on adding extra access control to elevator calling buttons and i would like to identify the connector type of the wires connecting elevator buttons to the elevator panel

I have tried Micro JST 1.25MM 3-Pin Male & Female Connector Plug, it has the same Pitch Mating size of 1.25mm but unfortunately the connector itself is smaller than the original one.

[image: original connector against Micro JST 1.25MM 3-Pin]

[image: original connector against Micro JST 1.25MM 3-Pin]

[image: Mitsubishi elevator calling button original connector]

[image: Mitsubishi elevator calling button original connector]

[image: Mitsubishi elevator calling button original connector]

[image: Mitsubishi elevator calling button]

[image: Mitsubishi elevator calling button with Micro JST 1.25MM 3-Pin]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a guide how to identify connectors?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/386736/is-there-a-guide-how-to-identify-connectors)

Comment: You threw me off and sent me down the wrong path for 10 minutes with your incorrect dimensions. The pitch of the original connector is 1.5 mm, not 1.25 mm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it with my [Identiconn utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html).

It's a [JST ZH](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/index.php?series=287): 1.5 mm pitch.

https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_1p5&s=ZH

- Male header: [S3B-ZR-SM4A-TF(LF)(SN)](https://www.digikey.com/short/vpmrm27q)
- Female plug housing: [ZHR3](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/ZHR-3/608602)

[image: JST ZH]

{Digikey}

Comment: Visual inspection confirms your answer, thanks a lot for your help and sorry for incorrect dimensions.